# Ripple ledger time format?

Tags: ripple, timestamp

I am wondering what is the format used in Ripple ledger time? For example, one of the most recent ledgers had `close_time` of `447299110`. I initially thought it was UNIX time, but the current time was `1393983976` - an order of magnitude of difference.

What is the Ripple ledger time format and how to convert from a UNIX time to that format?

Comment: https://ripple.com/wiki/JSON_format#time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ripple times are seconds since 1/1/2000 00:00 UTC. You can add 946,684,800 to a Ripple time to convert it to a UNIX time. If you are writing code to convert from Ripple times to UNIX times, please do your math in a 64-bit variable, not a 32-bit one.